# Convert code to reusable object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code, part of it shown below, that I call multiple times to modify an element on the page:

```
if ($('.el').length == 0)
{
    $('<div class="el active">Good job!</div>').hide().appendTo('body').fadeIn();
}
else
{
    $('.el').fadeOut(function()
    {
        $('.el').html('Good job!').addClass('active').fadeIn();
    });
}
```

Since I call this same piece of code multiple times (with varying messages and different classes at times), I want to make it so that I can simply do something like:

```
$('.el').messager({
    message: 'Good job!',
    class: 'active'
});
```

How can I convert what I have into what I need?

Comment: can you please create a jsfiddle with both html and js part.It will be fine even if that is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look up [how to extend jquery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.fn.extend/). something like this should do the trick (I have not tested the code) :

```
$.fn.extend({
  messager:function(options){
    var self = this;
    self.fadeOut(function(){
      self.html(options.message).addClass(options.class).fadeIn();
    });
  }
});
```

after calling the above method once after jQuery is loaded in your page. you can then call your method as in:

```
$('.el').messager({
  message: 'Good job!',
  class: 'active'
});
```

Comment: How would I extend without giving an element as input, like `$.messager()`?

Comment: i believe i have answered the question you put upthere :). this is a candidate for a seperate question as in adding functionality to the jQuery or '$' namespace.